# How to get passed data laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, parameter-passing, octobercms

I use `October CMS` which is running on `Laravel` and have a `/api/:page_id` page which for now only returns a link. My goal is to send `id` of any page to `api` when I open that page. Here is code for `/api/:page_id` :

```
function onInit()
{
    $page_id = $this->param('page_id'); 
    $pageURL =  "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/".$page_id;
    echo "Your full link is : <br><a href=\"".$pageURL."\">Link</a>";

}
```

I just don't know how to send parameter to `api`. Here is, for example, a snippet from a page I want to use for this:

```
function onStart()
{
  $this->page['baseFileName']);
  /* code to send baseFileName to api page */
}
```

Comment: Please provide more info

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel, you have a routes folder which contains routes for api requests in `api.php`. Edit your base route here such as -

```
Route::get("/{page_id}", "MyAPIController@onStart");
```

And your request handling method `onStart` would be as such -

```
function onStart(Request $request, $page_id)
{
    // $page_id variable holds the page id
    // Laravel throws an internal error if there is no id parameter in the url
}
```

then you can send a get request to the url `http://myurl.com/<page_id>`